# Looping tokenizer and notepad display

Tags: java, file

Our assignment is to retrieve a file and categorize it and display it in another file. Last name first name, then grade.

I am having trouble with getting a loop going because of the error

```
"java.util.NoSuchElementException"
```

This only happens when I change the currently existing while I loop I have. I also have a problem of displaying the result. The result I display is all in one line, which I can't let happen. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


class Grade
{
    public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException

    {
        //declaring     
        String line = "";
        StringTokenizer st;
        String delim = " \t\n\r,-";
        String token;
        String firstname;   
        String lastname;
        String grade;
        String S69andbelow="Students with 69 or below\n";
        String S70to79 ="Students with 70 to 79\n";
        String S80to89= "Students with 80 to 89\n";
        String S90to100= "Students with 90 to 100\n";
        int gradeint;
        double gradeavg = 0;
        int count = 0; 
        File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
      File outputFile = new File("output.txt");
        FileInputStream finput = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
      FileOutputStream foutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

      FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputFile);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

        Scanner std = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(S69andbelow);        
        //reading linev
        line = scanner.nextLine();

        st = new StringTokenizer(line, delim);
        //avoiding selected characters
        try
        {
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {



                firstname = st.nextToken(); //<----error started to happen 
                lastname = st.nextToken(); //here
                grade = st.nextToken(); //and here
                //storing tokens into their properties

                gradeint = Integer.parseInt(grade);
                //converting token to int

                gradeavg = gradeavg + gradeint;
                //calculating avg

                count++;
                //recording number of entries

            if (gradeint <=69)
            {
                S69andbelow = S69andbelow + lastname + " " 
                        + firstname + " " + "\t" + grade + "\n";
            }   // saving data by grades    

            else if (gradeint >= 70 && gradeint <= 79)
            {
                S70to79 = S70to79 + lastname + " " + firstname 
                        + " " + "\t" + grade + "\n";
            }   // saving data by grades

            else if (gradeint >= 80 && gradeint <=89)
            {
                S80to89 = S80to89 + lastname + " " + firstname 
                        + " " + "\t" + grade + "\n";
            }   // saving data by grades

            else 
            {
                S90to100 = S90to100 + lastname + " " + firstname
                         + " " + "\t" + grade + "\n";
            }   // saving data by grades


}//end while

            System.out.println(S69andbelow + "\n" + S70to79 + "\n" 
                         + S80to89 + "\n" + S90to100);
                //caterorizing the grades

                gradeavg = gradeavg / count;
                //calculating average

                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

                out.write("The average grade is: " 
                        + df.format(gradeavg));


            System.out.println("The average grade is: " 
                        + df.format(gradeavg));



            Writer output = null;            

            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

            //  scanner.nextLine(S69andbelow);
            //output.write(S69andbelow + "\n" + S70to79 + "\n" 
        //               + S80to89 + "\n" + S90to100);
        //  output.close();


}
        catch( Exception e )
        {  
                System.out.println(e.toString() );
         }
        // Close the stream
        try
        {
            if(std != null )
               std.close( );


                                }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
             System.out.println(e.toString());
         }

}
}
```

Question has been answered. The final touches is as presented:
/*************************************
Program Name: Grade
Name: Dennis Liang
Due Date: 3/31/11
Program Description: Write a program 
which reads from a file a list of 
students with their Grade. Also display 
last name, first name, then grade. 
************************************/

import java.util.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class Grade
{
    public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException

```
{
    //declaring     
    String delim = " \t\n\r,-";
    String token;
    String firstName;   
    String lastName;
    String grade;
    String S69andbelow="Students with 69 or below\n";
    String S70to79 ="Students with 70 to 79\n";
    String S80to89= "Students with 80 to 89\n";
    String S90to100= "Students with 90 to 100\n";
    String all;
    int gradeint;
    double gradeavg = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int countTwo = 0; 
    File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
  File outputFile = new File("output.txt");
    FileInputStream finput = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
  FileOutputStream foutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

  FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputFile);
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

    Scanner std = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(S69andbelow);        

    try
    {
    String line, newLine = (String)System.getProperty("line.separator");
        //seperating lines
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
        //Will only work if the file is properly formatted
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

    if (st.countTokens() == 3)
        {
        firstName = st.nextToken();     
        lastName = st.nextToken();
        grade = st.nextToken();
        gradeint = Integer.parseInt(grade);
        //retrieving tokens
        gradeavg = gradeavg + gradeint;
        //formula for avg
        count++;
        //avg count

        //organizing by grades
      if (gradeint <=69)
    {
        S69andbelow = S69andbelow + newLine+ lastName + " " 
                + firstName + " " + "\t" + grade + newLine;
    }   
         else if (gradeint >= 70 && gradeint <= 79)
    {
        S70to79 = S70to79 +newLine+  lastName + " " + firstName 
                + " " + "\t" + grade + newLine;
    }   

        else if (gradeint >= 80 && gradeint <=89)
    {
        S80to89 = S80to89 + newLine+ lastName + " " + firstName 
                + " " + "\t" + grade + newLine;
    }   

         else 
    {
        S90to100 = S90to100 + newLine+ lastName + " " + firstName
                 + " " + "\t" + grade + newLine;
    }
```

}
        else{
                countTwo ++;
                System.out.println("There is "+ countTwo + " person/people" +
                        " that require additional information" + "\n");
}                   //informing the user that there a how many people with 
}                   //missing information or too much.

```
            System.out.println(S69andbelow + "\n" + S70to79 + "\n" 
                     + S80to89 + "\n" + S90to100);
            //caterorizing the grades

            gradeavg = gradeavg / count;
            //calculating average

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
            //formating



            System.out.println("The average grade is: " 
                    + df.format(gradeavg));
            //displaying


            Writer output = null;            

            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
            //make file
            output.write(newLine + S69andbelow + newLine + S70to79 + newLine 
                 + S80to89 + newLine + S90to100);
            output.write("The average grade is: " 
                    + df.format(gradeavg));      
            //outputing to file      
            output.close();
            //saving
```

}
        catch( Exception e )
        {
                System.out.println(e.toString() );
         }
        // Close the stream
         try
        {
            if(std != null )
               std.close( );

```
                            }
     catch( Exception e )
    {
         System.out.println(e.toString());
     }
```

}
}

Comment: You might want to add the "homework" tag.

Comment: Can you at least post the line number where the exception happens, maybe part of the stacktrace?

Comment: I commented where it was in the coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check st.hasMoreTokens() before each time you call st.nextToken()

As far as the new line, windows requires \n\0

Alternatively, you can use System.getProperty("line.separator") which gives you the correct newline for each OS.

```
String line, newLine = (String)System.getProperty("line.separator");
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
//Will only work if the file is properly formatted
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
firstName = st.nextToken();
lastName = st.nextToken();
grade = st.nextToken();
gradeint = Integer.parseInt(grade);

gradeavg = gradeavg + gradeint;

count++;

                    if (gradeint <=69)
        {
            S69andbelow = S69andbelow + lastname + " " 
                    + firstname + " " + "\t" + grade + newLine;
        }   
        else if (gradeint >= 70 && gradeint <= 79)
        {
            S70to79 = S70to79 + lastname + " " + firstname 
                    + " " + "\t" + grade + "\n";
        }   

        else if (gradeint >= 80 && gradeint <=89)
        {
            S80to89 = S80to89 + lastname + " " + firstname 
                    + " " + "\t" + grade + newLine;
        }   

        else 
        {
            S90to100 = S90to100 + lastname + " " + firstname
                     + " " + "\t" + grade + newLine;
        }


}
```

Comment: So, I have to have 3 while loops?

Comment: I don't know what your input file looks like but perhaps you might want to parse out each line separately (nested loops perhaps)

Comment: Can you point it out?? (the \n\0)
the input file is:Bill Clinton 85 (enter)
Al Gore 100 (enter)
George Bush 95 (enter)
Hillery Clinton 83(enter)
John McCain  72(enter)
Danna Green 87(enter)
Steve Delaney 76(enter)
John Smith(enter)
Beth Bills 60(enter)

Comment: String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
//parse line here
}

Comment: Grade.java:61: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method readLine()
location: class java.io.FileReader
   while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                       ^

Comment: I meant to say 'in', not 'reader' as far as which variable is concerned.

Comment: alright, now it gives me that error of no elements so after the firstname we make another while? and another one after last name?

Comment: Use the code I put up in the answer: line.split(...) instead of StringTokenizer

Comment: I just added your :
String[] parts = line.split(" "); after my first while.

Comment: what about the the things after the //? , add those too?

Comment: That's pseudo-code that I commented out that you have to write in proper java. I want to leave some work for you...

Comment: We haven't learned that yet....., I'm new to Java, as well. We're also suppose to be using tokens only, the professor doesn't give us credit for what she hasn't taught us yet.

Comment: currently waiting for a peer to check it/review

Comment: Done. Also, you have to increment the count (count++;) inside of the while loop so you know how many people's grades you're averaging.

Edit: Missed a "\n". Replace it with newLine variable.

Comment: isn't it already inside the while loop? the file is input.txt

Comment: Oops, my fault. Didn't see it.

Comment: Okay, I replaced the while loop with the revised one. It gives me the element error. I believe that's expected.  So what's next? fixing that error?

Comment: putting all of the contents (below the StringTokenizer) inside an if statement: if(st.countTokens() == 3){/*the rest of the code inside the loop here*/}

Comment: wouldn't that give me trouble with the input file in this link?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575511/help-please-while-loop-and-tokenizer-and-reading-files

Comment: I assume by (enter) you mean new line, correct? Which line is giving you trouble (print out the line before tokenizing it and post the line that's right before the exception)

Comment: yes. the part of the tokenizing part. It always give me this error.
java.util.NoSuchElementException (tokenizing part is where the firstName = st.nextToken(); ,the problem started out here)

Comment: actually, I just got it to organize and read the inputfile. Now I have to somehow take that results and organization and display it into a output.txt file.

Comment: thank you for your time and effort, I really appreciated this so much. Is there anything I can do for you within my powers? (i'm going to leave this tab up daily to await your answer)